# How to write associations between two tables which have two foreign keys between them?

Tags: sequelize.js

There is a table "users" and another is "messages". Messages has two foreign keys, "authorId" and "receiverId" noth are foreign keys to the "users table". I am getting an error while initializing the DB.

I have created the following associations:

```
MessageDb.belongsTo(UserDb, {foreignKey: 'receiverId', as: 'receiver', targetKey: 'id'});
UserDb.hasMany(MessageDb, {foreignKey: 'receiverId', sourceKey: 'id'});

MessageDb.belongsTo(UserDb, {foreignKey: 'authorId', as: 'author', targetKey: 'id'});
UserDb.hasMany(MessageDb, {foreignKey: 'authorId', sourceKey: 'id'});
```

SequelizeAssociationError: You have used the alias receiver in two separate associations. Aliased associations must have unique aliases.

SequelizeAssociationError: You have used the alias author in two separate associations. Aliased associations must have unique aliases.

Answer (score 1):

That message doesn't make sense to me.  You might try adding an alias for the both of the hasMany associations, e.g.

```
UserDb.hasMany(MessageDb, {as: 'whatever', foreignKey: 'receiverId', sourceKey: 'id'});
```